# Problems with transfering single quotation marks in the command

Tags: c#, npgsql

I am writing a C#.NET WinForms application. I am currently implementing and testing a few database queries with `NpgsqlFactory`. I have the problem that (I assume) the characters `''` and `', '` are not recognized correctly.
When I run this line

```sql
STRING_AGG(CONCAT(XY.PropertyNameHere, ''), ', ' ORDER BY XY.PropertyNameHere) AS TableNameHere,
```

In pgAdmin4, everything works, but not in the program.
I have already tried to build different strings, i.e. `"', '"` or `", "`, but I get different error messages.

> 42P01: missing entry in FROM clause for table »projectNameHere«.

> String has a length of zero.

Apparently I cannot transfer these characters correctly in the command.

Comment: You must not build applications that are susceptible to SQL injections (and you must not interpolate/concatenate queries). Instead, use prepared statements to bind dynamic parameters to your query.

Comment: Please show your full code where you create the SQL command batch.

Comment: What is the purpose of concatenating an empty string? Shouldn't this be [COALESCE](https://www.dbvis.com/thetable/postgresql-coalesce-function-handling-null-value/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

I have now found a way that works. It's a mixture of all your answers and comments.

The first thing I've learned is that I should put the table names in quotes more often, so that capitalization doesn't matter. The error "*missing entry in FROM clause for table »...«*" is caused by this. 
But that doesn't matter now, because I have added the SQL file to the project, read it completely and execute it. There are no more problems with character handling.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

C# (excerpt)

```
string path = @"C:\Users\path\file.sql";
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    return List<T> // insert whatever you need;
}
string script = File.ReadAllText(path);
using (Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection connection = new Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand m_createdb_cmd = new Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand(script, connection))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (System.Data.Common.DbDataReader dr = m_createdb_cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
             while (dr.Read())
             {
               // Process each row here
             } 
         }
         connection.Close();
     }
}
```